# Rails routes issue using Phusion Passenger/Apache2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, phusion

Note: App is using Rails 3.2.1 and Ruby 1.9.3.

I'm attempting to set up a rails app using Passenger and Apache 2. When the applications is initially created it loads the default rails page fine using the default index.html file in /public.

The problem arises when I run `rails generate controller home index` and delete the index.html file. Then, in my routes.rb file I added `root :to => "home#index"`. I then get an error saying 'We're sorry, but something went wrong.'

My error log says `File does not exist` and when I add back in the index.html it loads fine again.

So, it seems it is still looking for the index.html file even after I delete it.

I'm probably missing something very obvious, so any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you provide us a full stack trace from your production log?

Comment: systho, I apologize for no response. Unfortunately, it did not work. I may try your solution again as it is always possible I overlooked something, but for now it remains broken.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've defined your root to `"home#index"`, you must have a HomeController with an index method and a view located in `app/views/home/index.html.erb`

Usually the controller method "prepares" the data for the view and this means that most controller methods finish with a call to `render`, giving it options for the view.

This pattern is so usual that you needn't call render if you just want to display the standard view. And the standard view is located in `app/views/[controller_name]/[action_ame](.[request_format])(.[precompilation_format)`

If you have the old index.html file in the public folder, then the static file is served and your controller is not triggered.  If you do not have that file, your controller is triggered and your index method is now trying to find an "index" file but in `app/views/home/index`.

The `request_format` is optional and is usually omitted if your site is html only. it becomes useful when your action can either respond with html, json, xml, ...

The `precompilation_format` is usually erb for html request_format but there are many more (haml, rabl, builder, ...)